# Combining Scheduling and Multiprocessing in python script

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, scheduling

I am trying to run a script in which a specific function, `run_script`, is run at specific times using Scheduling as well as parallel with the same function with varying arguments using Multiprocessing.

I have tried using Threading as well, however I still run into the same problem. The scheduling part works fine, but they still run in sequence, i.e. first `run_script(1)` and second `run_script(2)` and so on, instead of getting output of these functions at the same time.

In this simplified script below the output generated should be something like:

```
This is the 1 script...
This is the 2 script...
This is the 3 script...
This is the 4 script...
This is the 1 script...
This is the 2 script...
This is the 3 script...
This is the 4 script...
...
```

However this is the output that is being generated:

```
This is the 1 script...
This is the 1 script...
This is the 1 script...
...
This is the 2 script...
This is the 2 script...
This is the 2 script...
...
This is the 3 script...
This is the 3 script...
This is the 3 script...
...
This is the 4 script...
This is the 4 script...
This is the 4 script...
...
```

Of course the original function of the script is much more complex, but this simplified version should show what I am trying to achieve.

```
import schedule, time
from multiprocessing import Process


def run_script(n):
    p = 1
    while p < 1000:
        print(f"This is the {n} script...")
        p += 1

def procc(n):
    proc = Process(target=run_script, args=(n,))
    proc.start()
    proc.join()

rows = [1,2,3,4]

print("Assigning Schedules")
for row in rows:        
    # print(name)
    schedule.every(10).seconds.do(procc, row)

print("Starting schedule...")
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Is there any way in which to alter the code to get them to run at a schedule and as multi-processes or perhaps a whole different approach to achieve the same goal? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You want to schedule a single task to run every 10 seconds and that task runs 4 sub-tasks in parallel using a multiprocessing pool of size 4, which is allocated just once.

I have changed the demo to use Python's built-in `sched` module:

```py
import sched
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool


def run_script(n):
    t = time.time()
    for _ in range(3): # For demo purposes
        print(f"This is the {n} script being run at time {t}", flush=True)

pool = None

def procc():
    global pool

    rows = [1,2,3,4]
    # Create pool only once!
    if pool is None:
        pool = Pool(4)
    pool.map(run_script, rows)

# Required by Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
    #while True:
    # Just run 3 times every 10 seconds starting in 10 seconds from now:
    for _ in range(3):
        s.enter(10, 1, procc)
        s.run()
```

Prints:

```None
This is the 1 script being run at time 1666185329.4817867
This is the 1 script being run at time 1666185329.4817867
This is the 1 script being run at time 1666185329.4817867
This is the 2 script being run at time 1666185329.4857864
This is the 2 script being run at time 1666185329.4857864
This is the 2 script being run at time 1666185329.4857864
This is the 3 script being run at time 1666185329.4877844
This is the 3 script being run at time 1666185329.4877844
This is the 3 script being run at time 1666185329.4877844
This is the 4 script being run at time 1666185329.4897864
This is the 4 script being run at time 1666185329.4897864
This is the 4 script being run at time 1666185329.4897864
This is the 1 script being run at time 1666185339.4934042
This is the 2 script being run at time 1666185339.4934042
This is the 1 script being run at time 1666185339.4934042
This is the 3 script being run at time 1666185339.4934042
This is the 4 script being run at time 1666185339.4934042
This is the 2 script being run at time 1666185339.4934042
This is the 1 script being run at time 1666185339.4934042
This is the 3 script being run at time 1666185339.4934042
This is the 4 script being run at time 1666185339.4934042
This is the 2 script being run at time 1666185339.4934042
This is the 3 script being run at time 1666185339.4934042
This is the 4 script being run at time 1666185339.4934042
This is the 1 script being run at time 1666185349.5159597
This is the 2 script being run at time 1666185349.5159597
This is the 3 script being run at time 1666185349.5159597
This is the 4 script being run at time 1666185349.5159597
This is the 1 script being run at time 1666185349.5159597
This is the 2 script being run at time 1666185349.5159597
This is the 3 script being run at time 1666185349.5159597
This is the 4 script being run at time 1666185349.5159597
This is the 1 script being run at time 1666185349.5159597
This is the 2 script being run at time 1666185349.5159597
This is the 3 script being run at time 1666185349.5159597
This is the 4 script being run at time 1666185349.5159597
```

By the way, in your current code you start a single process and then immediately wait for it to complete by calling `join`. There is nothing gained by it since the main process is doing nothing while the child process does some work. That work could have just been done by the main process without starting a new child process.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am going to try and integrate this with my application and get back to you!